# when add sql column non-Clustered to the table the select with inner joing take too much time to excuate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have table contains more than 4 million record which make the select query take long time to execute so i decided to add non-clustered column to reduce the time, and that work fine which reduce it from 2 minutes to less than 1 second. 
but i discovered later that this change make some problem when executing other procedure with inner join to this table, this make the execution take too much time (more than 7 minutes). i don't know why this is happening

```
SELECT   [MessageID],
         SystemMinorStatus.EnglishDescription as EnglishStatusDescription
FROM [dbo].[Message]  
inner join SystemMinor as SystemMinorStatus 
on SystemMinorStatus.MinorID = [Message].Status]
WHERE     
[Message].[SubscriberID]= 22781 AND 
[Message].[IsDeleted]= 0
ORDER BY sendDate DESC
```

and some time give me this error message 
"Transaction (Process ID 74) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."

anybody have an explanation for this behavior

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock indicates that you have some other code that locks the table for edit or inserts, maybe in a bad way.

You could add "with (nolock)" after table name to ignore locks when reading but this might get inconsistent data.

You should also try to check activity on the sql server to try to find out what queries there is that take long time, Profiler is good for this, add an filter to only include queries that take more than say 1000 ms then lessen this until you get hits or increase if you get many hits and start to check what is going on.

Also check any indexes you have, the query should definitely not take long time normally, I have much heavier queries running on tables with a 100 million rows that execute in .1 sec or less.